# python script run by cron not logging output

Tags: python, django, logging, cron

I have a python script that is scheduled to run by cron. I can see the cron job is running this script when looking in the syslog `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`. But then when I open the file am logging the output I don't see any entries.

Crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * root run-one $PY $RASROOT/manage.py runscript listen_for_updates >> /var/log/updates.log 2>&1
```

python script:

```
def run():
    while True:
        print('Waiting for updates...')
```

Note: on running the script manually on the server it is logging, and I see output in the file.

Comment: If it's a Python script, why not write it to the file from script in append mode?

Comment: The problem is not in how I write, because when running the script manually, I see output in the log file.

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Did you find any solution?